# ORA-00604 when commit transaction either in plsql or application

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-text

I have `organization` table with below structure:

```
create table organization (
    id number(10) not null,
    parent_id number(10),
    title varchar2(255 char),
    hierarchy_code varchar2(255 char)
);
alter table organization
  add constraint fk_parent_id foreign key (parent_id)
  references organization (id);
```

that has column named `hierarchy_code` that contains hierarchical code of each organization, for example if we have organizations as below:

```
  department A
  |
  |__ office 1
  |   |
  |   |__ room A
  |   |   |__ room A1
  |   |   |__ room A2
  |   |
  |   |__ room B
```

the records of this table look likes this:

```
 ________________________________________________
| id | parent_id | title        | hierarchy_code |
|-------------------------------------------------
| 1  | null      | department A | 1              |
|-------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 1         | office 1     | 1001           |
|-------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 2         | room A       | 1001001        |
|-------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 3         | room A1      | 1001001001     |
|-------------------------------------------------
| 4  | 3         | room A2      | 1001001002     |
|-------------------------------------------------
| 5  | 2         | room B       | 1001002        |
 ------------------------------------------------
```

I generate value of `hierarchy_code` with this procedure:

```
create or replace procedure after_save_organization(id_var       number, old_parentid number, new_parentid number) is
  old_hierarchy_code        varchar2(255 char);
  new_hierarchy_code        varchar2(255 char);
  parent_new_hierarchy_code varchar2(255 char);
  sub_str1                  varchar2(255 char);
  str1                      varchar2(255 char);
  number_                   number(10);
begin

  select p.hierarchy_code
    into old_hierarchy_code
    from organization p
   where p.id = id_var;

  select hierarchy_code
    into parent_new_hierarchy_code
    from organization
   where id = new_parentid;

  select max(p.hierarchy_code)
    into str1
    from organization p
   where p.parentid = new_parentid
     and p.hierarchy_code != old_hierarchy_code;

  if str1 is not null then
    sub_str1 := substr(str1, 0, length(str1) - 3);

    number_           := to_number(substr(str1,
                                          length(str1) - 2,
                                          length(str1)));
    number_           := number_ + 1;
    new_hierarchy_code := sub_str1 || case
                           when length(number_) = 1 then
                            '00'
                           when length(number_) = 2 then
                            '0'
                         end || number_;
  else
    new_hierarchy_code := parent_new_hierarchy_code || '001';
  end if;

  update organization po
     set po.hierarchy_code = new_hierarchy_code ||
                            substr(po.hierarchy_code,
                                   length(old_hierarchy_code) + 1,
                                   length(po.hierarchy_code))
   where exists (select pp.id
            from organization pp
           where po.id = pp.id
          connect by prior pp.id = pp.parentid
           start with pp.id = id_var);
end;
```

everything is ok, but for custom organizations, after change `parent_id` when call the procedure to regenerate hierarchy code, procedure executed completely but when want to commit changes, i get this error:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-50610: internal error: drexdsync
DRG-50857: oracle error in drekrtd (reselect rowid row locator)
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.SYNCRN", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: Have a look at [Oracle Support Document 2289208.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2289208.1) which describes this error. (Or public version [here](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2289208_1.html), but you still need to log in to MoS to see the details...)

Comment: @AlexPoole i haven't access to that document, could explain more about that or post an answer here?

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to reproduce content from there (since it's only available to customers with support contracts), and I couldn't write an answer without essentially plagiarising it. And it's not really a programming question, as it's a problem inside Oracle, not with your code. Do you have a DBA with access? The short version is you seem to have a text index missing internal tables, which needs to be recreated, but the MoS doc shows how to identify it.

Comment: @AlexPoole is right: the Oracle Support T&Cs expressly forbid the re-publishing content. If your organisation doesn't have an Oracle Support contract then you may be out of luck.